# I'm trying to open a CSV file with Angular to set the content of this CSV to a matrix and publish it on an interactive web

Tags: angular, csv

I'm unable to open the CSV, I tryed several different things but I'm stucked. Thank you if you can give me some help

I created the angular project but when I try to open the CSV from https service it doesnt open anything

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ngx-papaparse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-papaparse) for parsing csv.

```
<div class="box-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="csv_file">Select File</label>
        <input type="file" (change)="onFileSelect($event)" id="csv_file" multiple="false" />
    </div>
</div>

onFileSelect(event) {
    this.csvContent = event.target.files[0];
    const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(this.csvContent);
    reader.onload = (e) => {
        const csvData = reader.result;
        const options = {
            complete: (results, file) => {
                console.log(results.data); // it will give you the exact data as array
            },
            skipEmptyLines: true
        };

        // @ts-ignore
        this.papa.parse(csvData, options);
    };
}
```